# Unity destination Vector based on rotation and the amount to move

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue where I can't figure out the algorithm to find out the destination point based on objects rotation and the amount to move. I have to move to the direction of my rotation a certain amount, but I don't know how to calculate the destination point I end up being at. Example:

```
Object location = (0, 0)
Object rotation = 45
Amount to move = 4
```

with these variables the destination point would be (2.5, 2.5)

Example 2:

```
Object location = (0, 0)
Object rotation = 0
Amount to move = 4
```

and with these it would be (0, 4)

The problem is, I don't know how to calculate the destination point when I know those variables. I need an algorithm that will calculate the destination point, can somebody help with this? :)

Regards, Tuukka.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a mathematics question; ask on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why 2.5,2.5 is there any specific reason?

Comment: Amount to move? Would be the 'distance of move'?

Comment: @TheBook I was wrong, it isn't 2.5 approximately. See answers below. And yes, I mean that by amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    float homMuchToMove = 4f;
    float angle = 45f;
    float pointX = Mathf.Cos (ConvertToRadians (angle)) * homMuchToMove;
    float pointY = Mathf.Sin (ConvertToRadians (angle)) * homMuchToMove;

    public float ConvertToRadians(float angle)
    {
        return (Mathf.PI / 180f) * angle;
    }
```

For these values you will get both points at `2.828427f`

Comment: The x coordinate is the cosine, the y coordinate is the sine. For 45° x=y so that works out, but generally this gives the wrong answer. Try e.g. with a 90° angle, this code gives you (4,0) when it should be (0,4) (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates). Exchanging `Sin` and `Cos` makes it correct :).

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt it should give (4,0)...?

Comment: A 90° Rotation in a mathemtical positive sense is counter-clockwise, so 90° would be standing straight up. If you move from (0,0) 4 units straight up, it gives you (0,4).

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I see.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a strictly algorithmic question where you want to calculate the destination point (i.e. no game object to move around, but abstract data), you can do this:
Consider the two-dimensional plane in cartesian coordinates, (i.e. the standard x/y system). Let O be an object at point `(0,0)`. From your "destination point" (2.5, 2.5) I can assume that you want the following thing:

[image]

So `45°` is the angle and `4` (`amount to move`) is the length of the line segment you want to move along. Starting from (0,0), this end point can be calculated using sine and cosine by using the formula for the polar representation of a point:

[image: formula2]

But actually, that image is wrong, which we'll see in the following computation. If the movement is along the line with a slope angle of 45°, you'd land a little bit elsewhere.

Anyways, for this example, alpha would be `45°` which is pi/4 in radians (you get this by dividing by 180 and multiplying with pi), and the radius r would be `4` (the amount we want to move), so we'd have calculated the destination point as:

[image: formula3]

If the point is located anywhere in the room (not at `(0,0)` but at `(x_0, y_0)`), then you can still add it as an offset:

[image: formula4]

So in code you'd write:

```
 public static Vector2 ComputeDestination(Vector2 origin, float amountToMove, float angle) 
 {
      //convert degrees to radians 
      var rad = angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
      //calculate end point
      var end_point = origin + amountToMove * new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(rad), Mathf.Sin(rad));
      return end_point;
 }
```

Comment: Oh, I understand it now. I got to those same results by applying cos and sin, but they screw me up on certain rotations. This is an excellent answer also but I'll give accepted answer to @Jerry Switalski for being first. Thanks!

Comment: While these answers are highly admirable, this simply **is not the forum** for arithmetic questions. It should be on math.SE, perhaps. But not here. There is a HUGE problem with clutter in the Unity3D tag.